# Why doesn't for-each method in java not throw an exception when a Function type argument is passed instead of Consumer?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

Why doesn't [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) method in java not show a compiler error when a Function type argument is passed instead of Consumer? Here both of the lines are returning a boolean value for every element in the stream but only 2nd line gets a compilation error? Is there any other property of *lambda expression* for such scenario?

Here's my code:

```
Stream.of(1,2,3,4).forEach(a->a.equals(1));//line 1

Stream.of(1,2,3,4).forEach(a->{return a.equals(1);});//line 2
```

Comment: `a -> a.equals(1)` can be interpreted as a consumer: it takes an argument and does something with it. `a->{return a.equals(1);}` cannot be interpreted as a consumer, because it explicitly returns a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding why the **first line** works: there's an explanation in [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3):

> Generally speaking, a lambda of the form `() -> expr`, where `expr` is a statement expression, is interpreted as either `() -> { return expr; }` or `() -> { expr; }`, depending on the target type.

The above comes with the following example (good coincidence, this is very similar to your example):

```
// Consumer has a void result
java.util.function.Consumer<String> c = s -> list.add(s);
```

This simply means that the compiler ignores the return type for the expression, as though your code were simply this (which is valid for a void method):

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4).forEach(a -> {
     a.equals(1);
});
```

---

And regarding the second line, [the spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2) says:

> A block lambda body is void-compatible if every return statement in the block has the form `return;`.

In your case, though, `{return a.equals(1);}` does not meet this rule. Void methods don't return a value.

An easy way to understand this is to consider that the compiler applies method body validation rules (such that the body must be compatible with the declaration `public void accept(T t)`) - as mentioned in the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

Answer (score 3):

In the first line you provided a valid `Consumer` which takes an argument `int a`. This is what `Stream.forEach` expects. The fact, that the consumer will additionaly return a value doesn't matter. The returned value will not be evaluated, it will be discarded.

The second line contains a statement which returns a `boolean`. As this statement has a return value, it doesn't comply with the method of `Consumer` which takes an argument but is declared `void`. Thus this gives the compile-time error: *Void methods cannot return a value*

JLS [15.27.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2) says:

> A block lambda body is void-compatible if every return statement in
>   the block has the form return;.

Thus the method returns without an explicit return value.

Regarding the return statement JLS [14.17.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-ReturnStatement) says:

> A return statement with no Expression must be contained in one of the
>   following, or a compile-time error occurs:
>
> - A method that is declared, using the keyword void, not to return a
>     value (§8.4.5)

Applying this to the second line results in the following code:

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4).forEach(a -> { a.equals(1); return; });
```

Further notes:
By returning the value of `equals` in the second line this statement doesn't become a `Function`. It's still just a statement.

An exception will not be thrown as an exception can only be thrown on runtime. Since the code doesn't compile, it cannot be executed. As specified in the JLS a compile-time error is issued.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, in the first line you have Consumer as returned value is ignored.
But in the second line you return result explicitly so expression became type of Function.